# Firebase auth returning "getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@7f42afc"

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a flutter app that uses firebase auth. Today I had to kill a dart process, and, since then when I try to login or create a user, it returns getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@7f42afc and doesn't create (or retrieve) the user.

I already ran flutter clean, but that just made it work once.
My system is a linux mint 19.1.

Flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Linux, locale pt_BR.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at /home/lucas/flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (8 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/lucas/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-Q, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/lucas/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /home/lucas/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 33.4.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.33.0)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 2.25.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G950F • ce10171abd2be43c05 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

If i run that:

```dart
print('a');
_user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: pass
      );
print('b');
```

it prints 'a' and getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@7f42afc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it just upgrading firebase_auth to 0.7.0 (I have some modules that cannot upgrade to androidx), hope this help someone